# What does -> mean in library dash.el?

Tags: dash.el

What does the `->` mean here:

```el
(interactive 
  (list 
    (-> (dap--completing-read "Select configuration template: "
          (-mapcat #'funcall dap-launch-configuration-providers)
          'cl-first nil t))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of a Lisp macro provided by library `dash.el`. Checkout `C-h f`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate by providing what `C-h f` shows for `->`? Thx.
Bonus points for explaining what it does in the question's example.